# Creating a cordova app fails on Ubuntu

Tags: cordova, ubuntu

I'm just following the guide for creating a new corvoda app. As prerequisite, i had to install cordova by npm install -g cordova, which i did, and my cordova version is 4.3.1. And now trying the cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld gives me the error:

> Downloading cordova library for www...
>
> Error: HTTP error 404 retrieving version 3.6.3 of cordova for www

Any ideas?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Those cordova versions are a couple years old, so I suspect the top-level instructions don't work for Ubuntu. You might want to take a look at the platform-specific ones here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ubuntu/index.html

Comment: Right now these are my versions:
$ node -v
v4.8.7
$ npm -v
2.15.11
$ cordova -v
4.3.1
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS,
But i haven't gone though the 'Add an Ubuntu "click chroot"' process. Is that causing the issue?

Comment: $ node -v
v8.9.4
$ npm -v
5.6.0
$ cordova -v
8.0.0
It's working with these versions.